# If dark energy is responsible for the expansion of the universe, is it possible that it is also the force which creates dark matter?

Tags: particle-physics

In a science fiction story I am writing humans travel through space (only our solar system) using dark energy. In my imagining of the future scientists discovered that dark energy exists in a field which repulses mass. The explanation being that While gravity is the force which attracts massive objects, dark energy pushes them apart. in the story the reaction between this push and pull effect on space is the force which creates dark matter. (the fabric of the universe)

So my question is this:

If dark energy is responsible for the expansion of the universe, is it possible that it is also the force which creates dark matter?

Comment: Dark energy has an extremely low energy density in this era of the universe. It's of no technical use, as far as we can tell.

Comment: If it is quintessence dark energy, there are models identifying quintessence with inflaton. In such a case DE could indeed create DM (in a sense that inflaton/quintessence decays into matter particles, and dark matter too). Not sure about how realistic those models are though.

Answer (score 0):

What we know about dark matter isn't much, but we know that it must be fairly evenly distributed (think of a nebula of gas without the stars).  We know that dark matter doesn't group together like matter tends to do due to gravity.  Although we have not been able to detect dark matter, it is safe to conclude that it isn't affected by matter in any obvious manner.  If we assumed for a moment that dark matter existed in some sort of parallel universe (explaining why we cannot find any), it still wouldn't be the type of matter that is like ours.

Dark energy is just compensating for the large amounts of energy that is required to have accelerated expansion of the universe and the extent of our knowledge of its existence is a component in a formula.

Now given what we know, could dark energy *create* dark matter?  In a sense, matter is just frozen energy, so it is possible yes, assuming that it doesn't violate the law of conservation of energy (if it is anything like matter, it would require a lot of energy to generate a small amount of dark matter), however it would be a mistake to assume that dark matter were something tangible that you could put into a warp drive since it doesn't seem realistic (however, use your artistic license as you wish with that knowledge).

A, perhaps, more boring suggestion but certainly more realistic alternative for spaceship fuel would probably be antimatter.  In a controlled engine, it would offer the most efficient fuel by weight.

Comment: I think it is in a halo around large masses, no? not evenly distributed. It is the galactic rotation curves that require dark matter to be fitted .

Comment: @annav I think so, yes, but we are talking about galaxy dimensions here without concentrated areas.  That's what I mean by nebula of gas.. many overlapping areas of dark matter.

Comment: I was not suggesting to put dark matter in an engine. In the story ships use nuclear power plants and particle accelerators to generate Dark Energy. their ships are only able to generate small amounts of it (enough to repel themselves form massive bodies. And enough to repel objects in their way.)

Comment: @ErinKelly You could make the same proposal to generate energy, but by creating matter rather than dark matter.  Hoist heavy object onto turbine, create mass underneath to increase gravity, get more energy from heavy object as it falls than you used to lift it up.  Except, that's crazy.. Creating that much matter would require so much more energy than you'd get.   Dark matter repels, but not *more* than normal matter attracts with gravity (at least to my knowledge).